# Type Class Data Types

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

Having read the article [Scrap your type classes](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/05/scrap-your-type-classes.html), I re-implemented some of the ideas shown.
While doing that I came across something really strange: The Type Class - Type can be used as a type constraint! My question: Why is that?

My Code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

data IFunctor f = IFunctor { 
    _fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> f a -> f b 
}

-- this type checks...
_fmap2 :: IFunctor f => (a -> b) -> f (f a) ->  f (f b)
_fmap2 = \inst -> _fmap inst . _fmap inst
```

In GHCi the following thing happens:

```
>>> :t _fmap2 :: IFunctor f => (a -> b) -> f (f a) -> f (f b)
_fmap2 :: IFunctor f => (a -> b) -> f (f a) -> f (f b)
       :: IFunctor f -> (a -> b) -> f (f a) -> f (f b)
```

Comment: That's just a bug.

Comment: @augustss Has it been reported? If so, where?

Comment: Which ghc version do you have?

Comment: GHC doesn't really care about the difference between `=>` and `->` in type signatures like it's supposed to sometimes.

Comment: This doesn't work on GHC 7.8.2. It gives the error `Expected a constraint, but ‘IFunctor f’ has kind ‘*’`. I think older versions of GHC had a bug where they allowed `=>` to be used like `->` in certain situations, like Carl said.

Comment: @DavidYoung I think you can turn your comment into an answer to close this out as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work on GHC 7.8.2. It gives the error `Expected a constraint, but ‘IFunctor f’ has kind ‘*’`.

Older versions of GHC had a bug where they allowed `=>` to be used like `->` in certain situations. This is likely because internally type class constraints are passed as arguments in the form of method dictionaries.